# Product are not displaying on Category page

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [shape] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are trying to do sorting or aggregations on a text type field instead of a keyword.

You have 2 options :

1. Edit the query to apply on the keyword field (by default field.keyword)
2. Edit the mappings to the default field to be keyword instead of text